# How to click on Checkbox, Radio buttons and reCAPTCHA in UiPath Studio?

Tags: rpa, uipath

I have to put an input on the site from Excel file which I have done successfully. The only thing i got stuck with is, there are some check boxes, radio button and reCAPTCHA which I m not able to record it. Could someone lead me with this?

Scenario: Check boxes and Radio buttons should be clicked as per the Excel file. I'm adding a screenshot of it.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Answer (score 2):

The Check activity should do the trick, it checks boxes and clicks radio buttons. I'm not sure if it works with reCAPTCHA, it probably doesn't, but you can always work around that with Click Image.